# M210 DJI drone can't find UART pins

Tags: dji-sdk

I am currently working on the serial communication on the M210 drone from DJI and I would like to test a programm using the serial communication. I know there are UART pins on the expansion ports but I cant find the documentation on the constructor's website to know which pins belong to Rx and Tx.

If someone has the information or knows where to find it.

Ps: I looked all the documentation on DJI's website about M210 and found nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Page 40 of the [user manual](https://dl.djicdn.com/downloads/M200/20170930/Matrice_210_210_RTK_User_Manual_EN.pdf) you'll find this pin description:

[image: Pin Map]

I hope this helps

Comment: It is exactly what i was looking for, thank you so much!